# DebuggerDisplayAttribute method call with parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debuggerdisplay

Is it possible to call a method with parameter(s) within the [DebuggerDisplay attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? I did not find helpful information for this problem in the MSDN article [Using the DebuggerDisplay Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I try to call the `ToString` method with a string parameter `"d"`; but the following did not work:

```
[DebuggerDisplay(@"{ToString(""d"")}")]
public class ...
```

I know it is recommended to use a private property instead of complex expressions. But is it nevertheless possible with an expression?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? This works fine for me, sort of. If I mouse over a local it shows the DebuggerDisplay attribute, but in the locals/watch windows it shows ToString(). What is shown in locals/watch is controlled by the user setting in Tools > Options > Debugging, "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows" option. If this is checked, you always get ToString and DebuggerDisplay is ignored there.

Comment: @mikez I use VS 2015 Enterprise, all updates are installed. I tried it on a VM and there it works well too, but on my primary environment it always ignore the attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it will allow that.  But why cant you do this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay(@"{DebugDisplay}")]
public class ...

private string DebugDisplay
{
    get
    {
        return ToString("d");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is more a theoretical question. I implemented already a property like you suggested. But I am not sure if it is possible to call a method with parameters or not.